# Release build causes simple protobuf code to fail

Tags: c++, release, protocol-buffers

I have the following unit testing code, which basically copies an object by serializing and deserializing it:

```
FloatMat mat2;                                  
assert(mat2.ParseFromString(mat.SerializeAsString()));      

cout << mat.vec_size() << "\n";                             
cout << mat2.vec_size() << "\n";
```

When built using cmake debug mode, it gives, as expected:

```
2
2
```

But when built using cmake release mode, it gives:

```
2
0
```

I am not very familiar with building in release mode, please help! thanks!

Comment: Sure you have also regenerated and rebuild your protobuf code when building release?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you populate `mat2` in the `assert` macro (which is being evaluated only at the debug build)